# LaTeX in blogger (Google)

Tags: mathjax

I want to write equation as LaTeX in blogger so need to setup MathJax may be. If anyone have done this before then please suggest me what to do.

At first I opened the temple >> HTML of that temple >> then entered the cole before

```
     <script src='http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js' type='text/javascript'>
MathJax.Hub.Config({
 extensions: [&quot;tex2jax.js&quot;,&quot;TeX/AMSmath.js&quot;,&quot;TeX/AMSsymbols.js&quot;],
 jax: [&quot;input/TeX&quot;, &quot;output/HTML-CSS&quot;],
 tex2jax: {
     inlineMath: [ [&#39;$&#39;,&#39;$&#39;], [&quot;\\(&quot;,&quot;\\)&quot;] ],
     displayMath: [ [&#39;$$&#39;,&#39;$$&#39;], [&quot;\\[&quot;,&quot;\\]&quot;] ],
 },
 &quot;HTML-CSS&quot;: { availableFonts: [&quot;TeX&quot;] }
});
</script>
```

After saving I tried to run the latex equation but didn't work . :( 
[image]
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: While [tag:MathJax] uses LaTeX syntax, it uses Javascript and HTML's DOM model rather than TeX technology, making it mostly off topic for this site. You might try instead searching among the [questions tagged with mathjax on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mathjax), or in the official [mathjax-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/mathjax-users) Google group.